# grep - match anything but given filetype

Tags: linux, grep, regex

I want to clean out my music library so I don't get any more "search for suitable plugin" messages from Rhythmbox when it sutubles across some WMA-Relic.

I have the tools, but now I want to FIND these files. I can get a list of all music files with ls, then pipe this to grep and catch all the mp3s like this:

```
ls */* | grep \.mp3$
```

Now I want to filter OUT all the MP3s, how would I do that? I messed around a lot with ^ and ~ and ! but I never seemed to get anywhere. I KNOW for a fact there are a few WMAs in there, but why should I search manually when I have a computer xD

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`grep -v` will return all lines that don't match your search query

you can also use:

```
find . ! -name "*.mp3"
```

to do the whole thing in one command.

Comment: To be on the safe side, I'd go with -iname rather than -name to perform a case insensitive match. 

You may or may not have some .MP3 files sitting around, etc...

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at the `-v` switch to `grep`, which inverts matching.