# Get everything on line but match with grep

Tags: grep

I'm trying to get everything on the matched line excluding the match using grep.

If I have

```
#define VERSION 0.1
```

The command should echo

```
0.1
```

I saw [this](https://superuser.com/questions/109986/grep-match-anything-but-given-filetype) question, but I only want things on the same line.

I read the man page, but I don't see anything that matches my specific usage case. Would a different command possibly be better than grep for this?

Comment: So you're searching for `#define VERSION`?

Comment: Yeah. What I'm specifically doing is executing a shell command to get what VERSION is defined as and storing it in a macro in a Makefile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easy way to achieve this is piping grep's output to sed:

```
command | grep "^#define VERSION" | sed 's/^#define VERSION //'
```

You can achieve the same result using only sed if you use the `-n` switch and the `p` (i.e., print) pattern for the regular expression. This will replace and only print lines that have been modified:

```
command | sed -n 's/^#define VERSION //p'
```

See: [man sed](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?sed)

Answer (score 1):

If your version of grep supports perl regex you can do it like this:

```
grep -oP '(?<=#define VERSION )[^ ]*$'
```

Otherwise use two invocations of grep:

```
grep '#define VERSION' | grep -o '[^ ]*$'
```